# F9 button doesnt sets breakpoint, but navigating to some website

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

My F9 button stopped setting break-point in Visual Studio and I can't find the reason. When I press F9 I get the following:

[image]

Under `Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard`

Here `Debug.EnableBreakpoint`:

[image]

And here `Debug.ToggleBreakpoint`:

[image]

Comment: `Tools->Options->Environemnt->Keyboard`

Comment: I enterd to `Tools->Options->Environemnt->Keyboard ` and under `Debug.EnableBreakpoint` it says `F9 (Global)` , so it looks ok, but the problem still exists @MichaelRandall

Comment: What does the shortcut say next to the break point command on the menu bar ? `F9` ?

Comment: @MichaelRandall It says `Ctrl+F9 (Global)`, I tried also to press both `Ctrl` and `F9` but same problem, I added screenshot

Comment: @MichaelRandall and under `Debug.ToggleBreakpoint` the shortcut command is `F9` but

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fn is probably locked, Press Fn + Esc to release it

[related](https://superuser.com/a/1357859/855713)

Answer (score 2):

Was the same problem. It turned out that I had a screen recorder running on which the F9 key was also assigned. Look carefully if you have any other applications running where this key can be used.

Comment: yep, i have the same problem and solved by this way